# how to disable some issue in sonar metrics?

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

It is possible turn off some issue checking in sonar projects and how to do it?  I want to for example disable "Tabulation characters should not be used" or "Modifier Order".

Thank for help.

Comment: Ok , sorry for the confusion, I found the solution . I must login as admin and choice :

->    Quality Profiles
 ->   Java
 ->   Sonar way with Findbugs

and check or uncheck potential issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like keep the rule active while excluding certain parts of your source-code, you can use features of the the switch-off violations-plugin.

The plugin was deprecated with sonarqube 4.0, as it is now possible to use integrated features described in this part of the sonarqube-documentation:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

If you are using an older version of sonarqube you find the plugin here:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin